# Error with deployment of vaadin servlet (using vaadin CDI) in wildfly

Tags: vaadin, wildfly, cdi, wildfly-11

I'm trying to deploy a war based on vaadin CDI in wildfly 11 (from within eclipse) but I have the following error:

```
21:14:36,578 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vaadin.cdi.internal.VaadinCDIServlet from [Module "deployment.myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1096)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:273)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vaadin.cdi.internal.VaadinCDIServlet from [Module "deployment.myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:725)
... 6 more
```

It seems to have problems to get VaadinCDIServlet class.
These are my dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- The following 2 are necessary to vaadin CDI -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-cdi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have an empty beans.xml file under WEB-INF.
Anyone has idea of what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Your CDI api should be in "provided" scope, having it in default scope may cause odd issues.

I suggest to bootstrap your project with [the Viritin CDI archetype](https://github.com/viritin/viritin-cdi-archetype), then you get all stuff right from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Have you remembered to remove VaadinServlet from your main UI class?